# SSH not using public/private keys

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have a system where SSH-ing still asks for the password even though:

1. My public key is correctly in the `authorized_keys` file on the remote server.
2. My private key is stored as `id_rsa` in my `.ssh` directory.
3. Permissions on the local client and remote server are correct. This includes the home directories, the `.ssh` directories, the `authorized_keys` file, and the key files themselves.
4. SELinux is disabled on both client and server.

Additionally, `/var/log/secure` on the server reports the following error on each login attempt:

```
sshd[17110]: error: Could not get shadow information for <USER>
```

where I've replaced the actual username with the string `<USER>`.

What could be the cause of this and/or how do I get my SSH keys working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the public/private keys did not match **on the client system**. I fixed this by running:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub
```

This will generate the public key corresponding with the existing private key and write it to the `id_rsa.pub` file, thereby matching up the public/private keys again.

I could not find the answer to my problem in several of the Stack Exchange answers I found, so decided to ask/answer my own question here. How did this happen? What happened was that I had SSH keys working in the past, but at some point accidentally ran `ssh-keygen` again. This created a fresh pair of public/private keys. I realized this and tried to fix it by putting back my old private keys. As the server still had the old public key within the `authorized_keys` file, nothing needed to be changed there. Unfortunately, I did not change the public key on the client side leading to the current situation.

Comment: All this would have been impossible to guess given the information in the question... which again shows that really only the one in front of the computer can do proper debugging. BTW, you can use `-v` to put both `ssh` and `sshd` into verbose mode, that really helps in narrow down the cause.